# How to select for multiple fields with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I currently have a form that is displaying fields that I do not want it to. There are 3 input fields associated with one form and the same form is being rendered multiple times.

I have my template set up to check for when this was only one value. I need to change it so the template will check for all of the values present & then decide to render.

So for example,

I have,

Div_id_form-0-x,
Div_id_form-0-y,
Div_id_form-0-z,
Div_id_form-0-location__location_category__requires_coordinates

What selector can I use to grab all of these to use in my template?

I need to grab them for each form. Where it says form-0 I have several of these forms repeating.

Then in HTML I have something like this.

```
 $(function () {
            // Determine weather we are in a modal window.
            var context = $("#{{ contextId }}-form");

            console.log("this is the {{ contextId }}" )

            // Show required coordinates if location category requires them.
            context.find("#id_location__location_category__requires_coordinates").change(function () {
                if (context.find("#id_location__location_category__requires_coordinates").val() == 'Y') {
                    context.find('#id_needs_coordinates').removeClass('hide');
                } else {
                    context.find('#id_needs_coordinates').addClass('hide');
                }
            });

        });
```

Right now this is only checking for one value to determine whether to hide. I need it to check all of these for this value. Which is why I'm looking for a Jquery selector that can do such.

Comment: `"Div_id_form-0-x, Div_id_form-0-y, Div_id_form-0-z, Div_id_form-0-location__location_category__requires_coordinates"` are these classes? ids? or what?

Comment: These are the Id's of the div's I want to select.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a selector for IDs, you can use:

```
$("#Div_id_form-0-x, #Div_id_form-0-y, #Div_id_form-0-z, #Div_id_form-0-location__location_category__requires_coordinates")
```

Please see: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

**Update**

In the future, please clarify the entire issue and provide a proper example.

You can use the Attribute selectors.

```
$("[id^='Div_id_form-']")
```

This will select all IDs like:

- `Div_id_form-0-x`
- `Div_id_form-1-x`
- `Div_id_form-2-x`

You will then select all of those elements.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: Thank you for your response Twisty, appreciate it! I guess my main problem is that I can select those but I have several of the same form rendering. So where it's form-0-whatever that 0 is going to be incremented throughout. I'm trying to find a way to select those fields on each form. I then want to go into my template & say with that selector, check these forms, if X is in them, don't load this part of the form. I have the HTML Template code. I will add to the initial post. Thank you again.